# Is it a good idea to store LabView source code in git repository?

Tags: git, svn, labview

I am trying to choose best revision control system for a LabVIEW project.

In [this](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/4114/en/)  and [this](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/websearch/26EC5904169430CE8625706E00743997?OpenDocument) article from National Instruments i have found that it might be a good idea to use SVN.

But I was wondering if I could use git (because I am used to it), and what are possible downsides comparing to SVN  or any other version control system mentioned above.

As far as I know git is designed to store text files and LabVIEW source code are binary files.
Hovewer I have found that many [people](https://decibel.ni.com/content/groups/git-user-group?view=blog) are using LabVIEW with git. 
There are even [github projects](https://github.com/joerg/LabViewGitEnv), that integrates LabVIEW with git.

So generally is it a good idea to use git and what are pros and cons?

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but I have used LabVIEW with TortoiseSVN and a [TSVN toolkit](http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/211524) with much success in the past. I think the real problem with any source control system and LabVIEW is that you can't really do a diff comparison on two VIs to resolve any conflicts that might come up. I think this is more often a concern when working concurrently on a project with other developers.

Comment: You can do diffs using LVCompare.exe and merges doing LVMerge.exe, but at least the merge part can be a pain (although I'll admit I have very little experience with it, as we usually try to avoid the situation where it's needed).

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't know since I never used git, but the obvious major issue is merging, which can be much more of a pain in LV than in text - if you're planning on people working in parallel with other people and then merging, then that's the area I would look closely at. This isn't specific to git, but it can be more commonly needed with distributed systems. The other thing I would be concerned with is whether everyone you're working with can use the system without getting confused about the concept of local and remote repos.

We use SVN, which works reasonably well for the binary files (it stores a local copy for comparisons), and I'm guessing the only reason I would want to change to a DVCS (git, hg, etc.) is the ability to do local commits, which would make experimental code easier to do.

There are occasional discussions on the pros and cons of each and you can look one up. One relatively detailed one is this one, but it is from a few years back:

https://decibel.ni.com/content/blogs/Matthew.Kelton/2011/09/30/labview-and-versionsource-code-control--introduction

Comment: Thanks. that sounds like reasonable answer. I really appreciate the link to this nice article. I think problems with merging might be solved by using [joerg/LabViewGitEnv](https://github.com/joerg/LabViewGitEnv) project.